# Dynamically using GetDriveType

Tags: c++, winapi

I am very new to WIN32 C++. What I am trying to do is to dynamically define the type of each drive using GetDriveType function.

Here is my code

```
#include Windows.h 
#include stdio.h 
#include iostream 

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    // Initial Dummy drive
    WCHAR myDrives[] = L" A";  

    // Get the logical drive bitmask (1st drive at bit position 0, 2nd drive at bit position 1... so on)  
    DWORD myDrivesBitMask = GetLogicalDrives();  

    // Verifying the returned drive mask  
    if(myDrivesBitMask == 0)   
        wprintf(L"GetLogicalDrives() failed with error code: %d\n", GetLastError());  
    else  { 
        wprintf(L"This machine has the following logical drives:\n");   
        while(myDrivesBitMask)     {      
            // Use the bitwise AND with 1 to identify 
            // whether there is a drive present or not. 
            if(myDrivesBitMask & 1)    {     
                // Printing out the available drives     
                wprintf(L"drive %s\n", myDrives);    
            }    
            // increment counter for the next available drive.   
            myDrives[1]++;    
            // shift the bitmask binary right    
            myDrivesBitMask >>= 1;   
        }   
        wprintf(L"\n");  
    }  
    system("pause");   
}
```

But `GetDriveType(myDrives)` keeps returning value 1 which is "No Root Directory". If I use like `GetDriveType("C:\\")` it shows the correct result. How can I resolve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a leading space in `myDrives`.  `GetDriveType()` does not ignore leading spaces.  Remove it and your code will work.  See the below working example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // Initial Dummy drive
  WCHAR myDrives[] = L"A:\\";

  // Get the logical drive bitmask (1st drive at bit position 0, 2nd drive at bit position 1... so on)  
  DWORD myDrivesBitMask = GetLogicalDrives();

  // Verifying the returned drive mask  
  if (myDrivesBitMask == 0)
    wprintf(L"GetLogicalDrives() failed with error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
  else  {
    wprintf(L"This machine has the following logical drives:\n");
    while (myDrivesBitMask)     {
      // Use the bitwise AND with 1 to identify 
      // whether there is a drive present or not. 
      if (myDrivesBitMask & 1)    {
        // Printing out the available drives     
        wprintf(L"drive %s -type = %d\n", myDrives, GetDriveType(myDrives));
      }
      // increment counter for the next available drive.   
      myDrives[0]++;
      // shift the bitmask binary right    
      myDrivesBitMask >>= 1;
    }
    wprintf(L"\n");
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `myDrive[]` initialization data has two issues. It has an extra space before the drive letter, and it is not specifying the colon-backslash after the drive letter. The [documentation for GetDriveType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly mentions:

> *lpRootPathName [in, optional]*
>
> The root directory for the drive. **A
>   trailing backslash is required.** If this parameter is NULL, the
>   function uses the root of the current directory.

You should modify the declaration of `myDrives` as follows:

```
// Initial Dummy drive
    WCHAR myDrives[] = L"A:\\";
```

and then you can increment the drive letter in your loop as follows:

```
// increment counter for the next available drive.   
    myDrives[0]++;
```